# How to create a JavaCompile task under a Custom Gradle Task?

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have recently upgraded my gradle version from 3.0 to 5.6.4

I was getting the following error in one of my .groovy files and it worked fine with Gradle 3.0

`Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ‘:compileApp’ of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile`

A brief on what I'm trying to do, Im trying to create & bundle a .war file

```
**build.gradle**

tasks.create
( name: taskName, 
type: Class.forName("com.org.xyz.implementation.groovy"), 
overwrite: true) { 
app thisApp 
}
```

The implementation & bundling is defined in the following implementation.groovy file:

```
**implementation.groovy**

class implementation extends DefaultTask {

**@TaskAction**
def generate(){

#process 1

#process 2

// Here after process2, I would like to compile the processed .java files. So i'm creating a gradle task of type: JavaCompile with execute()

project.tasks.create (type: JavaCompile, name: 'compileSrcFIles') {
        source <source dir>
        destinationDir <destination>
        classpath = project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }.execute()

#process3
// Uses the compiled .class files from the above task and execution continues
    }
}
```

Now if i remove the .execute() i see that error is resolved, But the task is just compiled and no actions is performed.

I've learnt that execute() should be replaced by finalizedBy(), dependsOn & mustRunAfter(), But that doesn't really make any sense in my situation.

How can i call a JavaCompile task inside the @TaskAction() block of implementation.groovy?

Gradle version used : 5.6.4

Comment: You need a custom task that compiles your sources, and then have this task use the outputs of that task. Without a simple reproducible example it's impossible to be more accurate.